# Command line tool to index and search by file size & other metadata

Tags: linux, open-source, document-indexing, file-search, metadata

I have some filesystems, mostly ext (I'll include the various ext versions in that: ext2/3/4).  I would like to be able to do indexed searches to find files by approximate size in addition to by other attributes.  That is, software somewhat like recoll or `locate`, which would either use inotify or regular scans to update an index, and provide a way to find files by querying the index.

The software would differ from `find` in using an index rather than scanning the filesystem for each query issued.

The software would differ from `locate` in being able to use file metadata like file size to find files, rather than only file/path names.  Ideally it would also use inotify to stay constantly up-to-date rather than relying on regular scans.

The software would differ from recoll in concentrating on file metadata rather than file content.  Ideally not restricted to file sizes, but other metadata like mtime, file path (I'll count that as metadata), etc.

I would like to be able to use a command line tool somewhat similar to locate or find in order to be able to find files.  Ideally it would provide some sort of query language or a syntax similar to `find`, but if it just gave a file listing that could then be filtered further by find that might work too, in a pinch.

I'm aware recoll can search by file size.  I'd rather have a smaller, more efficient, tool that concentrates just on file metadata rather than content.